# How to compute an integral of a given function without SymPy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math

I'm having difficulties creating a simple for loop code to integrate a given function without using `SymPy`. I'm thinking using some sort of Riemann approximation but I don't know how to do this exactly. The code I have so far is:

```
def xsquared(x):
    n = 2
    return x**n

def integral(fun, xmin, xmax):
    total = 0
    for a in range(xmin, xmax):
        x = a
        total += fun(x*1.235)
    return total 

print(integral(xsquared, 0, 4))
```

The output gives `21.3` but how do I do this without inputting a number referring to the `"fun(x*1.235)"` part?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compute integral by Riemann means that you are computing the limit of Riemann's sum by making partitions innner ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral)).

For that, your function could have a new parameter `interval: dx` or maybe you could just guess the interval by splitting the full range into `N` equal sized intervals. Here is an example asking `dx` as argument.

Then, your function should be:

```
def riemann(fun, xmin, xmax, dx):
    total = 0
    a = xmin
    while a < xmax:
        total += fun(a + dx/2)*dx
        a += dx
    return total
```

**Example Outputs**

```
print(riemann(xsquared, 0, 4, 0.1))
> 21.330000000000013

print(riemann(xsquared, 0, 4, 0.25))
> 21.3125

print(riemann(xsquared, 0, 4, 0.5))
> 21.25
```

Analythic resolution gives: `64/3 ~ 21.33333`

You're aproximating then the integral by computing the area of the rectangle having:

- **height**: the function value at interval middle point `fun(a + dx/2)`
- **width**: the interval length (`dx`)

Note: if `xmax < xmin`, you should verify that `dx < 0`.